# Не могу применить стили другому классу при помощи :hover

Tags: html, css

Допустим я хочу поменять цвет блока при наведении на ссылку, но почему то ничего не работает. Видел видео где в стилях не было + между .link:hover и .block и все нормально работало

```
<body>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <div class="block"></div>
</body>
```

CSS styles

```
.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.link:hover .block {
    background: red;
}
```